# What json structured data (json-ld) format can I use for movie show times?

Tags: json, json-ld, structured-data

I'd like to achieve something similar to this on google search:
[image]

This is a shortened version of the json-ld structured data that I currently have:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "@id": "https://example.com",
  "name": "Wonka",
  "subjectOf": {
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListElement": [
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "1",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T14:30:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema One"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "2",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T17:00:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema One"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "3",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T19:30:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema One"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "4",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T22:00:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema One"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "5",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T14:30:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema Two"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "6",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T17:00:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema Two"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "7",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T19:30:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema Two"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "8",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T22:00:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema Two"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "9",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T14:30:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema Three"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "10",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T17:00:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema Three"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "11",
        "item": {
          "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "name": "Wonka",
          "startDate": "2023-12-20T19:30:00+03:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Cinema Three"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What structure can I use to achieve results similar to the screenshot? For context: The page is a movie landing page. A movie is screened in multiple cinemas. Each cinema has multiple show times for the movie across different dates, for instance, Cinema X > 1st Jan [1PM, 3:30PM, 10PM], 2nd Jan [...]

Comment: Small tip: https://example.com, along with a few similar domains, is explicitly reserved for use in examples and documentation, but "sample.com" is not.